# vim: How to show directory tree with vi command

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Every time I want to show directory tree, I do it like this: `vi [filename]`, then `:NERDTree` . How to directly show direcotry tree just with `vi [filename]`?

Comment: There is a lot of information about it on the github page of nerdtree https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree (see the FAQ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanna see directory tree on opening vi, just put

```
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
```

in your vimrc